# SuperCSV quote every exported cell

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv, quote, supercsv

I'm using superCSV for exporting bean data to CSV. I'd like every cell double quoted, not just the ones with special characters.

Now, using  CsvPreference.EXCEL_NORTH_EUROPE_PREFERENCE, even the cells with special characters won't get quoted. (With EXCEL_PREFERENCE setting the addresses that contain '.' get quoted.)

My goal is to export addresses, phone numbers, everything in a way that MS Office (Hungarian) can use and i.e. won't convert phone numbers like +36000000000 to 36000000000.

Comment: I'm a Super CSV developer - I'll take a look at this when I get home from work tonight and get back to you. It should be possible to work around this, but it sounds like a feature that we should add.

Comment: This is the best solution I've found so far http://sourceforge.net/projects/supercsv/forums/forum/718794/topic/2010277

Comment: FYI [Super CSV 2.0.0-beta-1](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/release_notes.html) is out now. It includes many bug fixes and new features (including Maven support and a new Dozer extension for mapping nested properties and arrays/Collections).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Update for Super CSV 2.1.0

Since Super CSV 2.1.0, you can now specify a `QuoteMode` via the preferences to enable quotes when they're normally not required. To quote every column, you can use the inbuilt `AlwaysQuoteMode`. If want to enable quotes for particular columns, use the `ColumnQuoteMode`. Please note that you can't disable quoting this way, you'd have to supply your own `CsvEncoder` to do that.

---

Thanks for bringing that [forum post](http://sourceforge.net/projects/supercsv/forums/forum/718794/topic/2010277) to my attention! Looks like Kasper didn't get around to implementing that feature. I'll see what I can do for the upcoming release :)

Instead of hacking the Super CSV source to add this 'quote everything' functionality, you could extend the Super CSV implementation in your own project . As you've mentioned, Super CSV only quotes the whole field if it contains special characters (quote, comma, etc) - it also does it if the field contains leading/trailing spaces.

With this in mind there's no reason you can't write your own `Writer` which overrides the `escapeString()` method (you just have to make sure it's not already quoted).

```
package org.supercsv.io;

import java.io.Writer;

import org.supercsv.prefs.CsvPreference;

public class QuoteAllCsvBeanWriter extends CsvBeanWriter {

    public QuoteAllCsvBeanWriter(Writer writer, CsvPreference preference) {
        super(writer, preference);
    }

    @Override
    protected String escapeString(String csvElement) {

        // perform normal escaping
        final String escaped = super.escapeString(csvElement);

        // add surrounding quotes if required
        final String quote = String.valueOf((char) preference.getQuoteChar());
        if (escaped.startsWith(quote) && escaped.endsWith(quote)){
            return escaped;
        } else {
            return quote + escaped + quote;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Came to almost the same solution, but I like yours better :) (I've checked only if it starts with a quote, and I'm using CsvMapWriter).

Comment: It's probably overkill, you're right, as the last char has to be a quote if the first one is!

Comment: @HoundDog when will a new version of SuperCSV being released? It has  been 4 years since the last release and there are so many quirks/bugs in 1.52. When looking at SCM activity, I can see only 5 commits this year - should we consider the project as dead?

Comment: @MRalwasser No it's very much alive! I've just been flat out at work the last few months. I'm hoping to push a release out in June. Sorry for the delay.