# Unwanted double quotes in generated CSV file

Tags: java, csv, file-io, opencsv, supercsv

I have created a CSV file using the Java code below:

```
String csv = rs.getString("UPLOAD_FOLDER_PATH")+".csv";
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));
String [] filevalues = new String[filevaluesarray.size()];

filevalues=filevaluesarray.toArray(filevalues);

writer.writeNext(filevalues);

writer.close();
```

I am getting the CSV file, but the content of the file has unwanted double quotes.

> Eg. "ABC","123","KDNJ"

I don't get from where these double quotes are added.

Comment: You are aware of the fact that CSV in general has a text recognition character (in your case double quote). This is probably `CSVWriter`'s default, and you can probably change that.

Comment: What causes the problem? The generated CSV should be properly opened by any software with these.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This worked for me

```
CSVWriter writer = 
    new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv), ',', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
```

See the [CSVWriter javadoc](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/xref/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html)

Comment: FYI this constructor is deprecated, @giainel's answer appears to work though.

Comment: in the v5.2 CSVWriter constructor accepts **only two** formats.  **1-** new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filePath)).       **2-** new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filePath), CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END)

Answer (score 17):

You should probably clarify what you mean by 'unwanted' quotes.

1. I don't want it to quote *everything*, only the fields that contain
   embedded commas, quotes and newlines (quoting everything is unnecessary and
   makes my files bigger), or
2. I don't want anything quoted, and I understand that my CSV will be invalid if it contains embedded commas, quotes and newlines

If it's the first option, then opencsv doesn't support this - it either quotes everything or nothing. Take a look at [Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/) if you want an open source CSV library that only quotes when necessary (and can [quote everything too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10177293/1068649), if required).

If it's the second option, then go with Sheldon's answer, but just be aware the your CSV will be invalid if it contains embedded commas, quotes and newlines.

For example, if I'm reading your CSV file, how am I meant to know that the following is actually just a single record with 2 fields?

```
P Sherman, 42 Wallaby Way,
Sydney, AUSTRALIA
```

Whereas if it was quoted properly that would be obvious, i.e.

```
P Sherman, "42 Wallaby Way,
Sydney, AUSTRALIA"
```

FYI, here's the rules relating to quotes from [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) (the MIME type definition for CSV).

> **5**  Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however
> some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
> at all).  If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
> double quotes may not appear inside the fields.  For example:
>
> ```
>    "aaa","bbb","ccc" CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx
> ```
>
> **6**  Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
> should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:
>
> ```
>    "aaa","b CRLF
>    bb","ccc" CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx
> ```
>
> **7**  If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
> appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
> another double quote.  For example:
>
> ```
>    "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
> ```

Comment: +1 for the SuperCSV link. I was trying to do exactly what you describe in scenario #1 in your answer. SuperCSV does it perfectly. I've confirmed that it handles my most common problem characters (reading and writing): commas, single quote/apostrophe, double quote. Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: That's not true about quotes since last year. Now there's an option in CSVWriter.writeNext(String[] nextLine, boolean applyQuotesToAll), where applyQuotesToAll is "True if all values are to be quoted. False applies quotes only to values which contain the separator, escape, quote, or new line characters." (javadoc). Project continues to evolve, but I wouldn't say the same about SuperCSV.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't want the quotes in the values of the generated CSV file, you have to create the CSVWriter object in this way:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filePath),
    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
    CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
    CSVWriter.RFC4180_LINE_END);
```

The key is `CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER`. You can customize the values of the other constructor parameters.

Comment: Best answer because no annoying deprecation warning;

Answer (score 3):

on opencsv with version 5.4 just that fixed my same problem:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file), ',',
                                             CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
                                             CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
                                             CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);
```

Answer (score 1):

private void writeFile(String fileAbsolutePath , ListcsvLines) throws IOException{

```
    final char csvDelimeter = ',';
    CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(new File(fileAbsolutePath)),csvDelimeter,CSVWriter
                                                                                               .NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
    CSVParser parser = new CSVParser();

    for(String csvLine  : csvLines){
        String[] csvVals = parser.parseLine(csvLine);
        csvWriter.writeNext(csvVals);
    }
    csvWriter.flush();
}
```

Call : writeFile(fileAbsolutePath,csvLinesList);

Working example for Shamis's answer ,It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem with open csv and for fix the issue I use escaped character.

for ex:

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName), seprator,escaped_character);
```

In here open csv default use double quotes as escape_character(according to my knowledge)

In my case I use separator as pipe sign (|)

A2|G A A|Thilina|9022V|1|2|3|4|"Rubasingha"|'Abc|MATARA"|'No'|2012|1668.88

In here **"Rubasingha"** open and close the double quotes and in **'No'** also open and close the single quotes. these two work perfectly in default open csv

but when we use **'Abc** - only open single quotes - this also work fine

but **MATARA"** OR **"MATARA** - in here we have one double quote - in my case this generate error while reading the CSV using open csv

for fix the issue I reference this page (http://cs.swan.ac.uk/~csbob/teaching/java/JavaDemoNetbeans/opencsv-2.3/doc/)

There are constructors that cater for supplying your own separator and quote characters. Say you're using a tab for your separator, you can do something like this:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"), '\t');
```

And if you single quoted your escaped characters rather than double quote them, you can use the three arg constructor:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"), '\t', '\'');
```

You may also skip the first few lines of the file if you know that the content doesn't start till later in the file. So, for example, you can skip the first two lines by doing:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"), '\t', '\'', 2);
```

so I change the my default escape character to (^) sign without using double quotes as escape character.

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName), '|','^');
```

This is the way I fix the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation whereby I was facing data being displayed in my .csv file with three quotes on either side. This was due to my data having quotes in excel. The second I created a .csv file, I would open to see more quotations that was required. After much searching on the net I have found some code and tweaked to suit me as follows: -

```
 Public Sub OutputQuotedCSV()
 Const QSTR As String = ""
 Dim myRecord As Range
 Dim myField As Range
 Dim nFileNum As Long
 Dim sOut As String

   nFileNum = FreeFile
   Open "TheNameOfYourFile.txt" For Output As #nFileNum
   For Each myRecord In Range("A1:A" & _
          Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
      With myRecord
         For Each myField In Range(.Cells(1), _
             Cells(.Row, 256).End(xlToLeft))
           'I didn't want my Header Row touched but wanted it added into the csv file
           'There's probably an easier way but this worked perfectly for me
            If myField.Text = "HEADER 1" Then 
                        sOut = sOut & QSTR & _
                        Replace(myField.Text, QSTR, QSTR & QSTR) & "  "
                    ElseIf myField.Text = "HEADER 2" Then
                        sOut = sOut & QSTR & _
                        Replace(myField.Text, QSTR, QSTR & QSTR) & "  "
                    ElseIf myField.Text = "HEADER 3" Then
                        sOut = sOut & QSTR & _
                        Replace(myField.Text, QSTR, QSTR & QSTR) & "  "
                    ElseIf myField.Text = "HEADER 4" Then
                        sOut = sOut & QSTR & _
                        Replace(myField.Text, QSTR, QSTR & QSTR) & "  "
                    ElseIf myField.Text = "HEADER 5" Then
                        sOut = sOut & QSTR & _
                        Replace(myField.Text, QSTR, QSTR & QSTR) & "  "
                    ElseIf myField.Text = "HEADER 6" Then
                        sOut = sOut & QSTR & _
                        Replace(myField.Text, QSTR, QSTR & QSTR) & "  "
                    Else
               'I didn't want my first column to start with "," so I added the code below
                        If myField.Cells.Column = 1 Then
                            sOut = sOut & QSTR & _
                            Replace(myField.Text, QSTR, QSTR & QSTR) & QSTR
                        Else
                            sOut = sOut & "," & QSTR & _
                            Replace(myField.Text, QSTR, QSTR & QSTR) & QSTR
                        End If
                    End If
            Next myField
            Print #nFileNum, Mid(sOut, 1)
            sOut = Empty
        End With
    Next myRecord
    Close #nFileNum
End Sub
```

This code will strip away the extra quotations and leave the data with just single quotes at the beginning and end of the data. I hope this helps someone and if I have done something wrong in my format or not displayed the data correctly, forgive me. I am just trying to help others. Bear in mind, this isn't my code at all. I just got it working for me and I suspect others are trying to get what I achieved here.
The original code can be found here http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/textfiles.html#csvwithquotes

Comment: While this code may be helpful in some cases, it is *not* an answer to the OP's question. The OP asked why and how the double quotes were getting into his CSV file. You did not answer that question, posted code which would remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and still found some issues once I implemented the solution for version 5.3 of the open csv library.

It turns the data I needed to turn into a csv file contained the default escape character. So for the implementation to be done correctly I needed to suppress the escape character. So if your still having issues when opening up the file in Libre office or in Microsoft excel because of escape characters appearing use this solution:

```
new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(path),
            CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
            CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
            CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
            CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END    
        );
```