# remove double quotes from csv while using open csv

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

**Not a duplicate question.**

I am using open csv to write csv file.

```
FileWriter fw= new FileWriter("file.csv");  
CSVWriter cw= new CSVWriter(fw);
cw.writeAll(trade);
```

but the csv file it is creating contains double quotes on all values.

I found a solution to this in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969254/unwanted-double-quotes-in-generated-csv-file)

```
CSVWriter cw= new CSVWriter(fw, CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
```

but the method is depreciated can anyone suggest any alternate solution?

Comment: How are excess double quotes causing a problem?

I ask because if whatever consumes this CSV doesn't understand double quotes, perhaps `CSVWriter` is generating the wrong flavour of CSV and you need to find a tool or configuration that produces the expected flavour.

Comment: Why you're ignoring the constructor mentioned as "Please use ... instead" in the JavaDoc? Doesn't it match your need? Also your solution passes `CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER` incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JavaDoc](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.html) and the [Code](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.java#l78) you just need to use the currently supported (Not deprecated) constructor:

```
CSVWriter cw = new CSVWriter(fw, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR , CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);
```

Comment: CSVWriter extends AbstractCSVWriter which implements ICSVWriter: https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/ICSVWriter.java

Comment: You are right, I've just added the additional parameters to the OP's "working" answer.  Tweaked the solution now to account for the typo in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer in the [javadoc](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/xref/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html)

use this:

```
FileWriter fw= new FileWriter("file.csv");  
CSVWriter cw= new CSVWriter(fw);
cw.writeAll(trade,false); //here false means don't add quotes
```